# maven dependencies has some jars not mentioned in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have some jars in the maven dependencies of a project, which are not defined in pom.xml of the project. How is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

Because of transitive dependencies (libraries are dependant on other libraries)

see: [Transitive Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)

Comment: Is there a way to determine which jars are using these transitive dependencies

Comment: Yes, like Yanflea stated you can use `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 1):

Some jars you declare in the `pom.xml` depend on other jars, so you can end up with much more jars at the assembly level due to those transitive dependencies. You can launch this command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see all dependencies relative to a project.

Remember that you can also explicitely exclude some transitive dependencies [like this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

but you have to be entirely sure that you don't need them.